# angularjs ui-router templateURL not loading on plunker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, plunker

my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/3WRDCv?p=preview

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('txtbinge', ['ionic', 'firebase']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'ContentController',
    templateUrl: 'applayout.html'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'centerContent' :{
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      }
    }
  })

  //test plunker to see if stateParams are causing issues
  .state('crop', {
    url: '/crop',
    //template: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'applayout.html',
    controller: 'CropController'
  })

  .state('crop-image', {
    url: '/crop-image/:imageURI',
    //template: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'menu.html',
    controller: 'CropController'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/crop');
});
```

try loading a templateURL from `crop` or `crop-image` states. It doesn't seem to work. Which is very odd considering `app.home` does load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `templateUrl` is case sensitive...

Comment: Thanks! It's just taken me an hour of Googling to notice I had used templateURL